# Установка dotnet core 2.0 Ubuntu 16.04. Не удалось найти пакет dotnet-sdk-2.0.0

Tags: .net, ubuntu, .net-core

Ubuntu 16.04 Делаю по этой инструкции https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu

Все шаги выполняются нормально, но в конце пишет

```
~$ sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.0.0
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Не удалось найти пакет dotnet-sdk-2.0.0
E: Не удалось найти пакет с помощью glob «dotnet-sdk-2.0.0»
E: Не удалось найти пакет с помощью regex «dotnet-sdk-2.0.0»
```

sudo apt-get update делал не один раз.

При этом если набрать ~$ sudo apt-get install dotnet- и нажать таб то будет предложение автодополнения

```
dotnet-host
dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.0
dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.0-preview2-25407-01
dotnet-runtime-2.0.0
dotnet-runtime-2.0.0-preview2-25407-01
dotnet-sdk-2.0.0
dotnet-sdk-2.0.0-preview2-006497
```

Что ему еще надо?

Comment: Добрый день. Вы все шаги сделали? Я сам недавно заинтересовался .Net Core и по этому туториалу сделал "Привет Мир". Все взлетело, правда у меня была Ubuntu 15 версии и только эта команда для версии 14 подошла:sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-trusty-prod trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'

Comment: @JDo да. я все делал по туториалу. на 16.04 так и не удалось, а на 17.04 по тому же туториалу поставилось нормально.

Comment: @vitidev ставлю на Ubuntu 18.04 та же проблема.Ты решение не нашёл случаем?

Comment: @j.Atisto у меня не возникло проблем на 18.04 (core 2.1). Более того, по инструкции с 18.04 ставится даже на 16.04

Comment: @vitidev А, я мутаюсь! Ну буду пробовать. Спасибо!